# Set width to a specific child of a Row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a problem, i need backButton and actionsButtons (left and right) look whole. If there were no space, the title would be cut, but no the others buttons. How can i do that?
(I have all content in appbar title because i need a custom backbutton with more width):

```
AppBar(
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
          titleSpacing: 0,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              _getButtonBackIOS(),
              Text(title),
              Expanded(
                child: Row(
                  children: actions,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          actions: [],
          automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          leading: null,
        )
```

And looks like:

[image]

I want this:

[image]

Comment: you need second index ellipsis only or all??

Comment: That ellipsis would be auto because the text have `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,` and its parent would be smaller than the width of the text

Comment: make the text parent a particular width and the set ellipsis

Comment: That would @DeePanShu but he aslo added a row remember at it would move according to the width set. So the easy way is to make them actions instead and leave the title but still privide the width: Che the answer Below

Comment: @DeePanShu But i dont know what width is needed because on some devices it has enough space and on others it doesn't. I need it adjust automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you.wrap your Text widgets inside Row section in **Expanded** refer [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) or **Flexible** refer [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html)

```
 AppBar(
    title: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Text('Atras'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text('Filtros offertos'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text('title'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text('titleasdas'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text('title'),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text('titlesfsfsdf'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Your result screen like-> [image]

Comment: It works with a Expanded only to widget text, others widgets of row use correct space, thanks!

Comment: Most welcome @MiguelEscobarCalderon Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            titleSpacing: 0,
            title: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
              children: [
                const Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                const SizedBox(
                    width: 350,
                    child: Text(
                      "BlaBladwpuqontwetqret pqrtqpretoreq;e",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    )),
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(children: const [
                    Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                    Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
                  ]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
            leading: null,
          ),
```

[image]

Comment: This doesnt work for me, i said in question: "I have all content in appbar title because i need a custom backbutton with more width"

Comment: Will the custom back button be in the row or in the leading?

Comment: in the row, check the code i shared

Comment: Check the updated code. You'll have to set the width of the title to maximum knowing that some text may be small.